# how to insert multiple records in table using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api

Hi all I'm trying to insert multiple records using an api into a table. But I'm getting error like "Error connecting to database". How can i resolve it.

Below is my code

```
public function addToCart(){
   $input =  Input::all();
   $data['status'] = 0;
   $data['error'] = true;
   if(isset($input['user_id']) && array_filter($input['cart']) > 0 ){

        foreach($input['cart'] as $key => $val){


          if(!empty($val['quantity']) && !empty($val['price']) && !empty($val['sku']) && !empty($val['qrcode'])  && !empty($val['product_id']))

            {

                $totalPrice = $val['quantity']* $val['price'];

                    $cartId = DB::table('jocom_cart')->insertGetId(array(
                    'user_id'   => $input['user_id'],
                    'product_id'      => $val->product_id,
                    'sku'      => $val->sku,
                    'quantity'       => $val->quantity,
                    'price' => $val->price,
                    'total_price' => $totalPrice,
                     'qrcode' => $val->qrcode
                    )
                );

        }

    else{
        $data['message'] = 'All field are required.';

    }
    return Response::json($data);   
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about error?

Comment: Error connecting to database..  am getting this error only.actually i am trying to insert multiple records using api .when i write using foreach loop am getting this error.but when i want to insert single record without foreach.data inserting sucsessfully

Comment: Take var with array like `$cartId = [];` before saving and then use it like: `$cartId[] = DB::table('jocom_cart')->insertGetId(.....` Hope this helps!! also, have you multiple data in `$input['cart']` ??

Comment: yes multiple data in input cart

Comment: Then try the scenario which i provide.

Comment: Is it helped???

Comment: i tried it bro .but am getting status true .the values or not passing from foreach .and unable to insert data

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, you appear to be missing some closing braces (`}`) in your code.

Comment: am using laravel 4.2

Answer (score 2):

Create one array of the data and then pass the array to `insert function`

try to avoid query in the loop

```
$insertRecord = [];
foreach($input['cart'] as $key => $val){
    if(!empty($val['quantity']) && !empty($val['price']) && !empty($val['sku']) && !empty($val['qrcode'])  && !empty($val['product_id']))
    {
        $totalPrice = $val['quantity']* $val['price'];
        $insertRecord[$key] = ['user_id'=>$input['user_id'],'product_id' => $val->product_id,... ,... ,...]; All your column with value
    }
}
if(!empty($insertRecord)){
   Model::insert($insertRecord); // Eloquent approach
   DB::table('table')->insert($insertRecord); // Query Builder approach
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but am getting status  true .and unable to insert data

Answer (score 0):

Your record should be in array.
Table::insert(Array)

Comment: yes it is in array  $cartId = DB::table('jocom_cart')->insertGetId(array(

Comment: so, what the actual problem you are facing ?

Comment: just  use
 DB::table('jocom_cart')->insert(array);